# can not plot a graph using matplotlib showing error?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

trying to plot a graph ,  but showing error cannot import name 'TemporaryDirectory' from 'tempfile'

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
x= [1, 2, 3]
y=[4, 5, 6]
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

error below

```text
"C:\Users\sunil salat\PycharmProjects\MY FIRST PROJECT\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/sunil salat/PycharmProjects/MY FIRST PROJECT/DataVisualization.py"

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Users/sunil salat/PycharmProjects/MY FIRST PROJECT/DataVisualization.py", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Users\sunil salat\PycharmProjects\MY FIRST PROJECT\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 107, in <module>
    from . import _api, cbook, docstring, rcsetup
  File "C:\Users\sunil salat\PycharmProjects\MY FIRST PROJECT\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py", line 24, in <module>
    from matplotlib import _api, animation, cbook
  File "C:\Users\sunil salat\PycharmProjects\MY FIRST PROJECT\venv\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 29, in <module>
    *from tempfile import TemporaryDirectory
ImportError: cannot import name 'TemporaryDirectory' from 'tempfile' (C:\Users\sunil salat\PycharmProjects\MY FIRST PROJECT\tempfile.py)*

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: What is your python version in venv?

Comment: i am using 3.8.9

Comment: It seems major reason for this problem is using older python version. Can you put ```import sys``` and ```print(sys.version)``` before importing matplotlib and run it again? It might somehow be using python 2.x version.